# How to capture a string of text as a single field in awk?

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'm currently in the process of trying to write an awk script to process a bunch of DNS zone files. However, I am running into an issue in which certain DNS zone records (namely SPF and DKIM records in the form of TXT records) have spaces in them, which would cause awk to interpret the zone record's data as multiple fields. However, the one consistent trait they share is that a TXT record's data is always enclosed in double-quotes, and it's always the last actual field.

Here's a sample DNS zone that has a couple of SPF records just to show the structure of the input files:

```
; cPanel first:11.34.1.7 (update_time):1380693490 Cpanel::ZoneFile::VERSION:1.3 hostname:bentley.websitewelcome.com latest:11.36.2.4
; Zone file for digdeepdns.net
$TTL 14400
digdeepdns.net. 86400   IN  SOA ns1.digdeepdns.net. slucas.digdeepdns.net.  (
                        2013100200 ;Serial Number
                        14400 ;refresh
                        7200 ;retry
                        3600000 ;expire
                        14400 ;minimum
    )
digdeepdns.net. 86400   IN  NS  ns1.digdeepdns.net.
digdeepdns.net. 86400   IN  NS  ns2.digdeepdns.net.
digdeepdns.net. 14400   IN  A   192.185.57.22
localhost   14400   IN  A   127.0.0.1
digdeepdns.net. 14400   IN  MX  0   digdeepdns.net.
mail    14400   IN  CNAME   digdeepdns.net.
www 14400   IN  CNAME   digdeepdns.net.
ftp 14400   IN  A   192.185.57.22
digdeepdns.net. IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:70.84.243.130 a mx ip4:192.185.57.216 include:websitewelcome.com ~all"
cpanel  14400   IN  A   192.185.57.22
webmail 14400   IN  A   192.185.57.22
whm 14400   IN  A   192.185.57.22
webdisk 14400   IN  A   192.185.57.22
ns1 14400   IN  A   192.185.57.216
ns2 14400   IN  A   192.185.57.22
hg 14400 IN A  192.185.57.22
www.hg 14400 IN A  192.185.57.22
hg IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:70.84.243.130 +a +mx +ip4:192.185.57.216 ?all"
webdisk.hg IN A 192.185.57.22
```

The field separator for each of the records can be either a tab or a string of spaces. You can also see that not all of the records have an explicitly defined TTL as well, so I can't assume that $2 is going to be a number and $3 is going to be the literal 'IN'. The only common thread amongst all of the lines after the SOA is $1, which can easily be captured by `/[-_0-9a-z.]+/`. I'm not going for precision and verification; these DNS zones were generated by a script that pretty much guarantees they are RFC 1035 compliant.

The DNS zones are currently being processed by the following awk script:

```
#! /opt/local/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }
NR < 11 { print }
NR > 10 && /("[^"]+")/ { print }
```

Here's sample output of the script so far, which unfortunately ignores every single line -except- the two that are SPF records, but at least proves that the regex `/("[^"]+")/` works like a charm:

```
; cPanel first:11.34.1.7 (update_time):1380693490 Cpanel::ZoneFile::VERSION:1.3 hostname:bentley.websitewelcome.com latest:11.36.2.4
; Zone file for digdeepdns.net
$TTL 14400
digdeepdns.net. 86400   IN  SOA ns1.digdeepdns.net. slucas.digdeepdns.net.  (
                        2013100200 ;Serial Number
                        14400 ;refresh
                        7200 ;retry
                        3600000 ;expire
                        14400 ;minimum
    )
digdeepdns.net. IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:70.84.243.130 a mx ip4:192.185.57.216 include:websitewelcome.com ~all"
hg IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:70.84.243.130 +a +mx +ip4:192.185.57.216 ?all"
```

The first 10 lines of the zone file can be ignored (and are thus printed straight out by the script); they require some manual processing anyways. But lines 11 and onward need some better alignment, which I plan to accomplish with printf.

I'm starting off simple at first to figure out what I'm doing, but ultimately I am going to be using printf to replace spaces with tabs such that I can have the columns more neatly aligned. However, since IFS must be whitespace, this presents the challenge that the text data in the few TXT records in my DNS zones must be somehow globbed together and interpreted as a single input field for use with printf. Hence the regex that can capture an entire glob of text within double quotes.

I am specifically seeking a solution (or at least a very helpful hint that can lead me to the solution) in awk, since this learning experience is geared specifically for awk. I'm certain I could figure out a way this could be done in sed easily enough, but that's not really the point of my end goal.

I'm a little bit in over my head in this issue, and I could really use some help.

EDIT:

On recommendation, here's a sample of desired output (tabulations might be a bit borked, but the basic gist is to have 3 tabs space for column 1, and 1 tab for all of the others):

```
; cPanel first:11.34.1.7 (update_time):1380693490 Cpanel::ZoneFile::VERSION:1.3 hostname:bentley.websitewelcome.com latest:11.36.2.4
; Zone file for digdeepdns.net
$TTL 14400
digdeepdns.net. 86400   IN  SOA ns1.digdeepdns.net. slucas.digdeepdns.net.  (
                        2013100200 ;Serial Number
                        14400 ;refresh
                        7200 ;retry
                        3600000 ;expire
                        14400 ;minimum
    )
digdeepdns.net.     86400   IN  NS  ns1.digdeepdns.net.
digdeepdns.net.     86400   IN  NS  ns2.digdeepdns.net.
digdeepdns.net.     14400   IN  A   192.185.57.22
localhost           14400   IN  A   127.0.0.1
digdeepdns.net.     14400   IN  MX  0   digdeepdns.net.
mail            14400   IN  CNAME   digdeepdns.net.
www             14400   IN  CNAME   digdeepdns.net.
ftp             14400   IN  A   192.185.57.22
digdeepdns.net.         IN  TXT "v=spf1 ip4:70.84.243.130 a mx ip4:192.185.57.216 include:websitewelcome.com ~all"
cpanel          14400   IN  A   192.185.57.22
webmail         14400   IN  A   192.185.57.22
whm             14400   IN  A   192.185.57.22
webdisk         14400   IN  A   192.185.57.22
ns1             14400   IN  A   192.185.57.216
ns2             14400   IN  A   192.185.57.22
hg              14400   IN  A   192.185.57.22
www.hg          14400   IN  A   192.185.57.22
hg                  IN  TXT "v=spf1 ip4:70.84.243.130 +a +mx +ip4:192.185.57.216 ?all"
webdisk.hg              IN  A   192.185.57.22
```

The ultimate question is how I can have awk process the first 3-4 fields (depending on whether $2 is a number or 'IN') like normal, then for fields 5+, it would also need to be a conditional. Anything in quotes must be processed as a single field. I'd strongly prefer suggestions or pointers to help me find the solution to this.

EDIT #2:

On a somewhat related yet simultaneously unrelated side tangent. I can't seem to find a clear answer as to whether or not it's possible to nest pattern{statement} pairs as the statements in a pattern{statement} clause, like so:

```
patternA {
    patternAA { statements }
    patternAB { statements }
}
patternB {
    patternBA { statements }
    patternBB { statements }
}
```

Is this possible in awk? If so, that might help me to figure out how to do this script.

Comment: lot of stuff here. Hard to tell what your ultimate question. Can you reedit your question to include required output given the example input above? While a lot of people love bare rule/action pairs in awk, you might find that something of the form `awk '{ if (N$<11) { print }  else if (...) { something else } ; else { do this }}' input` might be better for your case of printing out the first 10 lines (for example). Good luck.

Comment: you can always nest testing of patterns inside std `/pattB/ { if($0 ~ patternBA) { ... } else if ($0 ~ patternBB) {...} else {... } }`  blocks as much as you want!. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There might be better ways to write this, but here it goes:

```
NR < 11 { print; next }
{
    hname = $1
    if ($2 == "IN") {
        port = ""
        dom  = $3
        addri = 4 
    }   
    else {
        port = $2
        dom  = $4
        addri = 5 
    }   
    addr = $addri
    if (dom == "TXT") {
        for (i = addri + 1; i <= NF; i++) {
            addr = addr" "$i
            if ( index($i, "\"") != 0)
                break
        }
    }   
    printf("%-30s\t%s\t%s\t%-10s\t%s\n", hname, port, "IN", dom, addr)
}
```

Comment: this line gets wrong output:   digdeepdns.net.                 14400   IN      MX              0

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /opt/local/bin/awk -f    
BEGIN{FS=" IN "}
NR<11{print;next}
{ split($1,a,OFS);printf "%-30s%-10s\t%s\t",a[1],a[2],FS
  l=split($2,b,OFS);printf "%-10s\t",b[1]
  for (i=2;i<=l;i++) printf b[i] OFS;printf RS
}


$ awk -f b.awk infile
; cPanel first:11.34.1.7 (update_time):1380693490 Cpanel::ZoneFile::VERSION:1.3 hostname:bentley.websitewelcome.com latest:11.36.2.4
; Zone file for digdeepdns.net
$TTL 14400
digdeepdns.net. 86400   IN  SOA ns1.digdeepdns.net. slucas.digdeepdns.net.  (
                        2013100200 ;Serial Number
                        14400 ;refresh
                        7200 ;retry
                        3600000 ;expire
                        14400 ;minimum
    )
digdeepdns.net.               86400              IN     NS              ns1.digdeepdns.net.
digdeepdns.net.               86400              IN     NS              ns2.digdeepdns.net.
digdeepdns.net.               14400              IN     A               192.185.57.22
localhost                     14400              IN     A               127.0.0.1
digdeepdns.net.               14400              IN     MX              0 digdeepdns.net.
mail                          14400              IN     CNAME           digdeepdns.net.
www                           14400              IN     CNAME           digdeepdns.net.
ftp                           14400              IN     A               192.185.57.22
digdeepdns.net.                                  IN     TXT             "v=spf1 ip4:70.84.243.130 a mx ip4:192.185.57.216 include:websitewelcome.com ~all"
cpanel                        14400              IN     A               192.185.57.22
webmail                       14400              IN     A               192.185.57.22
whm                           14400              IN     A               192.185.57.22
webdisk                       14400              IN     A               192.185.57.22
ns1                           14400              IN     A               192.185.57.216
ns2                           14400              IN     A               192.185.57.22
hg                            14400              IN     A               192.185.57.22
www.hg                        14400              IN     A               192.185.57.22
hg                                               IN     TXT             "v=spf1 ip4:70.84.243.130 +a +mx +ip4:192.185.57.216 ?all"
webdisk.hg                                       IN     A               192.185.57.22
```